# Hi i have some problems with a T-SQL using *

Tags: sql, t-sql, cross-apply

Group the ProductID orders, get a total by ProductID, the total of the orders and what represents the ProductID orders of the total order (that is a percentage). Columns Required: PercenofTotal (UnitPrice * Quantity), TotalAmount (UnitPrice * Quantity), PercentofTheTotal (UnitPrice * Quantity)

So this is my code, what i dont know is to do the percentofTheTotal and TotalAmount

```
SELECT P.ProductID, (P.UnitPrice * ODQuantity) AS tOTALaMOUNTByProductID, (P.UnitPrice * Quantity) as TotalAmount , (P.UnitPrice * OD.Quantity) as PercenofTotal 
From Products as P,
From OrderDetails as OD
Group by P.ProductID
```

Comment: `FROM`, `FROM`.  Your query does not make sense.

Comment: and if you are JOINing tables please explicitly declare them and avoid using commas

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you need to end up with here, but pointers below to help for a start

Comment: Looks like there is a missing dot between OD (a table alias) and Quantity (a column name) in the SELECT part where you declare 'tOTALaMOUNTByProductID'

Comment: You seem to want a JOIN rather than two FROMs together (this won't work - it's incorrect syntax)

Comment: You'll probably need to aggregate the UnitPrice and Quantity columns in some way (e.g. SUM or COUNT) for the GROUP BY to work

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to do something complicated with simple statements that are not correct. Something like this could possibly do what you want to achieve.

```
USE AdventureWorks2014
GO

SELECT  P.ProductID
       , SUM(P.StandardCost * OD.OrderQty) AS TotalAmountByProductID
       , MAX(SumTA.TotalAmount) AS TotalAmount 
       , (SUM(P.StandardCost * OD.OrderQty) / (MAX(SumTA.TotalAmount))*100) AS PercentOfTotal
FROM Production.Product as P
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail as OD on P.ProductID = OD.ProductID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                   SELECT max(pid) as pid, SUM(TA.TotalAmount) as TotalAmount
                    FROM
                       (  SELECT  '1' as pid, P.ProductID, SUM(P.StandardCost * OD.OrderQty) AS TotalAmount
                         FROM Production.Product as P
                         JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail as OD on P.ProductID = OD.ProductID
                          Group by P.ProductID
                       )AS TA
                ) AS SumTA ON SumTA.pid = '1'

Group by P.ProductID
ORDER BY PercentOfTotal Desc
```